# PHP formating numbers to locale and back

Tags: php, internationalization, locale, number-formatting

After a lot of research I am actually using the following function to format numbers to the locale setted by the user:

```
function number_format_i18n($number, $decimals=0) {
    $locale = localeconv();
    return number_format($number,$decimals, $locale['decimal_point'], $locale['thousands_sep']);
}
```

I'll use this to format numbers from DB.

But if I have a form where a user can enter a number, I need a function to format it back so I can save into the DB. Here I found this solution:

```
function number_format_en($number) {
    // $_SESSION['lang']['locale'] has the locale like de_DE, ar_AE, tr_TR, ...
    $fmt = numfmt_create($_SESSION['lang']['locale'], NumberFormatter::DECIMAL);
    return numfmt_parse($fmt, $number);
}
```

This works with the most locales I tested but not with everyone! As an example: if I use arabic (ar_AE):

```
$randomNumber = 3171003633.95;
$number2locale = number_format_i18n($randomNumber, 2);
// works as expected: 3,171,003,633.95
// now format it back:
$locale2number = number_format_en($number2locale);
// here I get this: 3.171
```

How can I format a locale entered number in a secure way "back" to en-format? Or is there a way to detect any kind of numberformat and format it to en-format so I can save it in the DB?

Answer (score 0):

So, don't know really if this is a good solution or not - but it seems to be working fine:

```
function number_format_en($number) {
    // first remove everything execpt -,.
    $cleanNumber = preg_replace('/[^\\d-,.]+/', '', $number);

    $last_dot = strrpos($cleanNumber, '.');
    $last_comma = strrpos($cleanNumber, ',');

    if($last_dot !== false || $last_comma !== false) {
        if($last_dot > $last_comma) { // decimal seperator = dot
            $decimal_point = '.';
            if(substr_count($cleanNumber, '.') > 1) {
                // could be totaly wrong 1,234.567.890
                // or there are no decimals 1.234.567.890
                // removing all dots and commas and returning the value
                return preg_replace('/[^\\d-]+/', '', $cleanNumber);
            }
        } else { // decimal seperator = comma
            $decimal_point = ',';
            if(substr_count($cleanNumber, ',') > 1) {
                // could be totaly wrong 1.234,567,890
                // or there are no decimals 1,234,567,890
                // removing all dots and commas and returning the value
                return preg_replace('/[^\\d-]+/', '', $cleanNumber);
            }
        }
    } else { // no decimals
        $decimal_point = false;
        $decimals = 0;
    }

    if($decimal_point !== false) {
        // if decimals are delivered, get the count of them
        $length = strlen($cleanNumber);
        $position = strpos($cleanNumber, $decimal_point);
        $decimals = $length - $position - 1;

        if($decimal_point == '.') {
            // remove all commas if seperator = .
            $cleanNumber = str_replace(',', '', $cleanNumber);
        } elseif($decimal_point == ',') {
            // remove all dots if seperator = ,
            $cleanNumber = str_replace('.', '', $cleanNumber);
            // now switch comma with dot
            $cleanNumber = str_replace(',', '.', $cleanNumber);
        }
    }
    return $cleanNumber;
}
```

I'll check the last dot or comma and depending on that I format the number, function returns the same count of decimals as the original number. there is a "known" bug: if someone enters a full number like 1.000.000 or 1,000,000 it returns 1000000.

As an example:

```
number_format_en('1.234.567,89') // 1234567.89
number_format_en('-1,234,567.89') // -1234567.89
number_format_en('1.234.567.89') // 123456789 (only dots)
number_format_en('1,234,567,89') // 123456789 (only commas)
```

Would be nice if someone can post a comment if this is a good way or not or an answer with a better solution :)

Comment: This does look a bit heavy-handed.  What is your interpretation of `1,000`?  How would you know if it means `one thousand with no decimal places` or `one with three decimal places`?  This seems like an unsolvable issue.  So basically, it will work until it doesn't work and when it doesn't work, it will fail silently so you will struggle to identify the issue.